# Textarea not accepting &nbsp; and &amp; whille saving pages content using ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax, textarea

My textarea is not accepting `&nbsp;` and `&amp;` whille saving pages content using AJAX and PHP.

This is editor page using textarea with ajax:

```
<html>
        <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script>
        function save(){
             var x = $("textarea").val();
             var data = 'c='+x;

     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'save.php',
         data: data,
         success: function(e){
             $("#s").html(e);
         }
     });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea>
<?php

$fn = "blank.html"; 

//FILE TO BE EDITED (FILENAME EDITABLE)

$file = fopen($fn, "r+"); //OPENS IT
$fr = fread($file, 1000000); //READS IT
fclose($file); //CLOSE CONNECTIONS
echo $fr; //SHOWS THE EDITABLE FILE HERE

?>
</textarea><br>
<input onClick="save()" id="x" type="button" value="Save"><br><br>
<span id="s"></span><br>
<a href="blank.html" target="_new">view file</a>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is `save.php` code:

```
<?php

$c = $_POST["c"]; 

//TEXT FROM THE FIELD


$f = 'blank.html'; 

//FILE TO SAVE (FILENAME EDITABLE)

$o = fopen($f, 'w+'); //OPENS IT
$w = fwrite($o, $c); //SAVES FILES HERE
$r = fread($o, 100000); //READS HERE
fclose($o); //CLOSES AFTER IT SAVES

//DISPLAYS THE RESULTS
if($w){
    echo 'File saved';
} else {
    echo 'Error saving file';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happen because of url encode. You should use `encodeURIComponent()` on your JavaScript params.

change

```
var x = $("textarea").val();
```

to

```
var x = encodeURIComponent($("textarea").val());
```

also your script can be simplified

```
 <script>
 $(function (){ 
   $("#x").click(function (){
     $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'save.php',
       data: { c:  encodeURIComponent($("textarea").val())}
       success: function(e){
           $("#s").html(e);
       }
     });    
   });
});
</script>
```

change input to

```
<input id="x" type="button" value="Save">
```

You should also stay to html standard. In this example it'll be good to bind event to submit form event and use `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you always pass your content through  `encodeuricomponent`

so your code will be `var x = encodeURIComponent($("textarea").val());`

Comment: how is this answer different than mine? :>

Comment: we answered at the same time, there was no answer when i came here